# Slow query when ordered by

Tags: mysql, sql, select, query-optimization, where-clause

The following query takes over 20 seconds to run on a 1.000.000 rows table

```
SELECT max(listing.category) AS category,
    max(listing.subcategory) AS subcategory,
    max(listing.created_at) AS date,
    listing.keystring AS listing_keystring
FROM listing
WHERE listing.privacy > 10
GROUP BY listing.keystring
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 10
```

If I remove the "order by" part the query takes less than 1 second to run.

According to the explain statement:
EXTRA says "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"
Type says "Index"
Key says "listing_idx_keystring_category"

Here the create table statement:

```
 'CREATE TABLE `listing` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bw` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `subcategory` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `place` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_hidden` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''0'',
  `privacy` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''20'',
  `keystring` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      GENERATED ALWAYS AS (concat(`bw`,`category`,ifnull(`subcategory`,''''),ifnull(`place`,''''),ifnull(`time`,''''))) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `listing_idx_privacy` (`privacy`),
  KEY `listing_idx_keystring_category` (`keystring`,`category`),
  KEY `idx_listing_created_at_privacy` (`created_at`,`privacy`),
  KEY `idx_listing_created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `idx_listing_bw` (`bw`),
  KEY `idx_listing_subcategory` (`subcategory`),
  KEY `idx_listing_category` (`category`),
  KEY `idx_listing_place` (`place`),
  KEY `idx_listing_time` (`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1500001
      DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
```

Is there anything that can be done to improve the speed?

I have tried adding different index combinations but with no luck...

Comment: Same question has been asked here numerous times, last time yesterday. Did you use the search bar on the top? You need to show at least some effort finding the answer by yourself.

Comment: Please provide  SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables.

Comment: Read and tried all solutions, but still no luck

Comment: Force different index, but why doy you need so  many indexes, that sisheer ressources wasting. all single idexes that are already in a combined index delete them unnccesary.

Comment: I have added all indexes trying different solutions found around here, will remove them eventually.

Comment: @nbk what index should I force? I have tried many and different combinations, but none seem to slow the query...

Comment: `WHERE listing. > 10`? The column name seems to be missing here.

Comment: updated the question, thanks, i accidentally deleted it before posting!

Comment: I suspect the result is not only slow, but also incorrect.  The 3 max's -- they may not be related.  For example you may be getting a max(category) that does not include the resulting max(subcategory).  Is that OK?

Comment: There query is too complex to be optimized as it stands.  It probably also involves _two_ sorts.  See `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON`.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
select 
    max(category) as category, 
    max(subcategory) as subcategory,
    max(created_at) as date, 
    keystring as listing_keystring
from listing
where privacy > 10
group by keystring
order by date
limit 10
```

I would start with the following index: `(privacy, keystring)`. This matches on the `where` predicate and the `group by` column. You don't have that index in place, so try it first.

You might also want to try: `(privacy, keystring, category, subcategory, created_at)`; that's quite a lot of columns, so I am unsure whether MySQL would actually consider it but it is sure worth trying; in the best-case scenario, MySQL would use that as a *covering index*, and execute the whole query by looking at the index only.

Note that blindly creating indexes on many columns combinations does not help. On the one hand, the indexing strategy needs to be tuned on a per-query basis. On the other hand, more indexes means more storage and more work for the database for every DML operation (`update`, `insert`, `delete`), for potentially no benefit in `select` queries. Unless you have a good reason to keep each and every existing index, I would suggest dropping them.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer! However I have tried both the solutions and there is no significant speed improvement.
If I select the (privacy, keystring) index the Explain states
null in the KEY section and
'Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort'.  

If I use the (privacy, keystring, category, subcategory, created_at) index the Explain states '
Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort'
 in the EXTRA and 
'idx_listing_privacy_keystring_category_subcategory_created_at'
 in the KEY section.